# Detecting Row-wise the the first dropout na (where only na or logicals follow)

Tags: r

Is there a possibility to detect for each row the the column from which on only NA or logicals follow? If something else follows, the NA should be ignored.

```
data <- tibble(
  A = c(NA, TRUE, 2, NA, TRUE),
  B = c(1, NA, NA, 0, TRUE),
  C = c(TRUE, FALSE, NA, NA, FALSE),
  D = c(FALSE, TRUE, NA, FALSE, TRUE)
)

    data
# A tibble: 5 × 4
      A     B C     D    
  <dbl> <dbl> <lgl> <lgl>
1    NA     1 TRUE  FALSE
2     1    NA FALSE TRUE 
3     2    NA NA    NA   
4    NA     0 NA    FALSE
5     1     1 FALSE TRUE
```

The output of the function should look like this one with one col representing the row number and the other one wether there is this type of NA (if not -> NA) and if so the column in which this dropout NA is located.

```
output
# A tibble: 5 × 2
    row Column_NA
  <dbl> <chr>    
1     1 NA       
2     2 B        
3     3 B        
4     4 C        
5     5 NA
```

Comment: Note vectors hold a single class, so the `A` and `B` vectors in your example don't contain any logical values as they've been coerced to a common class (numeric).

Comment: And also note that `1 == TRUE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function:

```r
func <- function(...) {
  dots <- list(...)
  isna <- which(sapply(dots, is.na))
  islgl <- sapply(dots, function(z) is.logical(z) | is.na(z))
  found <- FALSE
  for (ind in isna) {
    if (ind < length(dots) && all(islgl[-(1:ind)])) {
      found <- TRUE
      break
    }
  }
  if (found) names(dots)[ind] else NA_character_
}
do.call(mapply, c(list(FUN = func), data))
# [1] NA  "B" "B" "C" NA
```

Which we can convert with

```r
res <- do.call(mapply, c(list(FUN = func), data))
data.frame(row = seq_along(res), Column_NA = res)
#   row Column_NA
# 1   1      <NA>
# 2   2         B
# 3   3         B
# 4   4         C
# 5   5      <NA>
```

Comment: Do you know if its possible to adjust your function to look for logicals that are false instead of just logicals? Tried it with isFALSE but it didnt work. Thanks a lot once again.

Comment: Sure, change the inner portion to `islgl <- sapply(dots, function(z) is.na(z) | (is.logical(z) & !z))`, this produces `c(NA, NA, "B", "C", NA)` here. (This always assumes `z` is something for with `!` works, which includes logical, integer, and numeric, not strings, factors, timestamps, dates, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I somehow had some issues with !z. This seems to work fine  islgl <- sapply(dots, function(z) is.na(z) | (is.logical(z) & isFALSE(z)))

Comment: Do you mind if i build a package around this function and functions based on this detection? Might be really useful for people in my research area.

Comment: Feel free to use as needed. (I wouldn't mind a mention; perhaps as much as `ctb` in the package `Authors:` but not required.)